# Setting a future date based on a field value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, acrobat

I have an Acrobat form that accepts a date for a notice to a customer.  The customer has 20 days to respond, and I need the notice to calculate a field that auto-populates the correct day 20 day later.

I have the following code:

```
if (getField("chkCounterOffer").value != "On") {
     event.value = "";
}
else {
    var d = new Date(getField("fldNoticeDate").value);
    event.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", new Date(d.getMonth(),(d.getDate() + 20),d.getFullYear()));
    calculateNow();
}
```

but it's throwing an error.  The current date (`fldNoticeDate.value`) `02 Jul 2019` produces a future date of `07 November 1912`.

What am I formatting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your year needs to come first in your parameters.

```
event.value = util.printd("mm/dd/yyyy", new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(),(d.getDate() + 20)));
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp